# SOLR 4 - Can I do something similar to facet.field={!ex=category}category with face.pivot - is it possible?

Tags: php, lucene, solr, pivot, faceted-search

Can someone help me with proper syntax for the following request:

I have a facet count implemented on the category menu, i would like to show the menu like this:

```
CATEGORIES:
Computer Hardware (15)
->> Software (20)
Office Equipment (10)
```

basically even though that someone drills-down to one of the options of the menu to still have the other parent level categories show the counts.

With facet.field I can achieve it by doing something like:

```
&facet=true&facet.field={!ex=category}category_name&fq=      {!tag=category}category_name:Hardware
```

I would however like to do it with the `facet.pivot=category_name`,`category_id options`, because all of our SEO links were always based on the ID of the category and not the name, and with facet.field I have to query DB for each individual category_name to build the tree with the name and not id only.

So the question is: 
is it possible to do something like the facet.field filter on facet.pivot option?